# optimization streaming vbo openg

Tags: opengl, optimization, vbo, deferred-rendering

I'm rendering a top-down, tile-based world, using opengl 3.3, using fully streamed VBO's.

After encountering some lag I did some benchmarking and what I found was horrid!

[image]

Let me explain the picture. The first marked square is me running my game using the simplest of shaders. There is no lightning, no nothing! I'm simply uploading 5000 vertices and draw them. My memory load is about 20-30%, cpu-load 30-40%

The second is with lightning. Every light is uploaded as an array to the fragment shader and every fragment processes the lights. load about 40-50%. 100% with 60 lights.

The third is with deferred shading. First I draw normal and diffuse to a FBO, then I render each light to the default FB, while reading from these. load is about 80%. Basically unaffected by amount of lights.

These are the scenes I render:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, there's nothing fancy. It's retro style. My plan has been to add tons of complexity and still run smooth on low-end computers. Mine is a i7 nvidia 660M, so it shouldn't have a problem.

For comparison I ran warcraft 3 and it took about 50-60% load, 20% memory.

One strange thing I've noticed is that if I disable V-sync and don't call glFinish before swapbuffers, load goes down significantly. However, the clock goes up and heat is produced (53C*).

Now, first I'm wondering if you think this is normal. If not, then what could be my bottleneck? Could it be my streaming VBO? I've tried double buffering and orphaning, but nothing. Doubling the number of sprites basically increases the memory load by 5-10%. the gpu-load remains basically the same.

I'm aware this question can't be easily answered, but I'll provide more details as you require them. Don't want to post my 20000 lines of code here.

Oh, and one more thing... It fluctuates. The draw calls are identical, but the load can go from 2-100%, whenever it feels like it.

UPDATE:

my main loop looks like this:

swapbuffers

renderAndDoGlCalls

updateGameAndPoll

sleep if there's any time left (1/60th second)

repeat.

Without v-sync, glflush or glfinsih, this results in percentage used:

swap: 0.16934400677376027

ren: 0.9929640397185616

upp:0.007698000307920012

poll:0.0615780024631201

sleep: 100.39487801579511

With glFinish prior to swapbuffers:

swap: 26.609977064399082 (this usually goes up to 80%)

ren: 1.231584049263362

upp:0.010266000410640016

poll:0.07697400307896013

sleep: 74.01582296063292

with Vsync it starts well, usually the same as with glFinish, then bam!:

swap: 197.84934791397393

ren: 1.221324048852962

upp:0.007698000307920012

poll:0.05644800225792009

sleep: 0.002562000102480004

And it stays that way.

Comment: I think by using a profiler you can determine better where your bottleneck is.  You should have a lokk at [this](http://de.slideshare.net/CassEveritt/approaching-zero-driver-overhead) too.

Comment: Load as measured on which device? CPU or GPU? You're typically going to trade one for the other if you've got a handle on things. VSYNC usually lowers GPU load but may increase reported CPU load depending on the mechanism the driver uses to wait. The best approach to measure performance is probably to ignore load % altogether since it varies wildly depending on VSYNC and other artificial factors (such as pre-rendered frames) and look for frame time consistency. I don't see a graph of frame times anywhere.

Comment: I've made an update.

Comment: The load is meassured on the GPU. The CPU is at steady ~5%

Comment: I'm basically doing everything on the cpu except for the light calculations which are done in the shaders

Comment: Your main loop is architected very strangely. You should not introduce that artificial sleep on your own at the end. You would want to begin the buffer swap as early as possible (after the last command for the frame is sent) and let the driver handle any sort of necessary sleep. Otherwise what's going to happen is you will stage a frame, sleep potentially for longer than a VSYNC interval and _then_ on the _next_ loop iteration finally present your finished frame (which might be an entire 1-2 frames late at this point).

Comment: You are breaking pre-rendered frames this way with none of the input latency benefits that usually come from preventing the CPU from rendering ahead of the GPU. _You definitely need to re-arrange your main loop to make the CPU and GPU work together better._

Comment: I've tried all possible arrangements and this is what works best for me. This way I can utilize the cpu in parallel with the gpu, by doing simulation updates while the gpu writes to the backbuffer. If I call swapbuffer right after the actual rendering, the cpu thread will stall and not be able to do anything until the backbuffer is complete.

Comment: Let me clarify... If I call swapbuffers right after all opengl calls, my CPU stalls for 70% of update-time, letting me do nothing. This way, I give the GPU the longest possible time to finish the backbuffer before I call the swap again.

Comment: While I can still use the cpu...

Comment: I get what you're saying, but still not. The sleep is just there for times when V-sync is disabled to keep the computer burning up and not gobble up all resources. And if I disable the sleep, I'm still having the same problem. And about parallelism, how is put all opengl-calls in a command queue, stall the cpu and wait for the gpu to finish good parallelism? The whole point with my loop as of now is to put all opengl-commands as quickly as possible in the queue, flush it, then do stuff on the cpu while the gpu works in parallel, then swap the buffer. Don't take me as arrogant, just wondering.

Comment: @Jake: This is more than I can explain in the comments section here. I have written an answer that may help. If you have additional questions, please add them to the comments section of that answer. Putting commands in a queue and then allowing the CPU to continue onto the next frame instead of waiting for your refresh rate to roll around is tremendously helpful for CPU/GPU parallelism - but that doesn't happen when you block the CPU by sleeping. Also, Adaptive VSYNC is probably what you want. That throttles the CPU/GPU back when it is rendering too fast without the other issues of VSYNC.

Answer (score 1):

> Let me clarify... If I call swapbuffers right after all opengl calls, my CPU stalls for 70% of update-time, letting me do nothing. This way, I give the GPU the longest possible time to finish the backbuffer before I call the swap again.

You are actually inadvertently causing the opposite scenario.

The only time SwapBuffers causes the calling thread to stall is when the pre-rendered frame queue is full and it has to wait for VSYNC to flush a finished frame. The CPU could easily be a good 2-3 frames ahead of the GPU at any given moment, and it is not the current frame finishing that causes waiting (there's already a finished frame that needs to be swapped in this scenario).

Waiting happens because the driver cannot swap the backbuffer from back to front until the VBLANK signal rolls around (which only occurs once every 16.667ms). The driver will actually continue to accept commands while it is waiting for a swap up until it hits a certain limit (pre-rendered frames on NVIDIA hardware / flip queue size on AMD) worth of queued swaps. Once that limit is hit, GL commands will cause blocking until the back buffer(s) is/are swapped.

You are sleeping at the end of your frames, so no appreciable CPU/GPU parallelism ever develops; in fact you are more likely to skip a frame this way.

That is what you are seeing here. The absolute worst-case scenario is when you sleep for 1 ms too late to swap buffers in time for VBLANK. Your time between two frames then becomes 16.66667 + 15.66667 = 32.33332 ms. This causes a stutter that would not have happened if you did not add your own wait time. The driver could have easily copied the backbuffer from back to front and continued accepting commands in that 1 extra ms you added, but instead it blocks for an additional 15 at the beginning of the next frame.

To avoid this, you want to swap buffers as soon as possible after all commands for a frame have been issued. You have the best likelihood of meeting the VBLANK deadline this way. Reported CPU usage may go up since less time is spent sleeping, but performance should be measured using frame time rather than scheduled CPU time.

*VSYNC and the pre-rendered frame limit discussed will keep your CPU and GPU from running out of control and generating huge amounts of heat as mentioned in the question.*

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. I will digest this.

Comment: @Jake: My discussion lacks any diagrams, but I think you should take a look at the [following diagram](https://owtaylor.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/acx-loaded-large.png). It does not discuss pre-rendered frames, but if you picture yourself adding some sleep time to the orange buble, you can basically see what happens if you sleep past the time when the blue bubble starts (the final frame shown has this problem). The green bubble would be the driver in effect.

Comment: So, you're saying that swapbuffers doesn't stall if the previous gl-commands haven't finished? This would make sense to me if I had a couple of ready frames in a "backbuffer queue". But I don't think I do, since I only do one render-call per swapbuffers, leaving the GPU no other choice than to wait for the current frame to finish. Even if I did manage to put a few frames in a queue, then wouldn't there be alot of latency between input and what's on screen?